# Context-specific remap

Tags: vim

I have the following handy VIM map:

```
inoremap ( ()<Left>
```

However, sometimes I will enter Insert mode to add a function call around a variable, like so:

```
Was: $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $someTable;
 To: $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($someTable);
```

The mapping makes a redundant `)` after `mysql_real_escape_string(`. **Is there any way to refactor the mapping so that if there exists a character after the cursor, and the character after the cursor is not whitespace, then `)<left>` is not appended to `(`?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing that would mean entering "function territory". From there, why not go full gear into "plugin territory" and use a dedicated plugin like [delimitmate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) or [autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose) or the many variations on the same idea?